# SQL query inner join and where on the second table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a oracle database and I'm trying to query data in table1 and inner join with another table2 where one of the columns(date) is equal to the most recent date and another column in table2(built) is equal to 'yes'. This query below is not picking up the where function and can't pinpoint why

```
SELECT id, b, c, d 
FROM table1 a 
INNER JOIN table2 b on b.id = a.id 
WHERE b.date =(SELECT MAX(date) FROM table2) AND b.built = 'yes'
```

Actual query

```
SELECT m_tp_str, m_tp_trn, m_tp_dte, m_tp_buy, m_tp_qtyeq, m_tp_nom, m_instr, 
       m_tp_p, m_tp_status2 
FROM   HA_PRD_DM.TP_ALL_REP a INNER JOIN HA_PRD_DM.UDF_CURR_REP b 
           ON a.m_udf_ref2 = b.m_nb 
WHERE  b.m_rep_date2 = (SELECT MAX(c.m_rep_date2) FROM HA_PRD_DM.UDF_CURR_REP c)
   AND b.m_purpose = 'yes'
```

Comment: What does "not picking up the where function" mean?  Do you get an error?  Do you get zero rows?  Can you post some expected results?  I expect you mean to get the row with the `MAX(date)` _for each id_, but that is not what you say in the question and it's not what your query will do.  Some clarification will help.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I'm not getting any error or zero rows. I'm expected to have 5k rows but I'm getting over 1.5mm. And no on MAX(date) for each id. I want to retrieve all ID(can be duplicates) that has the max date

Comment: It is unlikely that this is the **actual** query (you are selecting `b` which is an alias for a table - so please don't answer **yes this is the actual query**). Please post the actual query, otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I tried adding an alias to the subquery subsequently but it did not change anything

Comment: @mathguy added actual query to my initial question

Comment: OK. The query looks correct (even without the unnecessary aliasing of the base table in the scalar subquery). Now, please do the following: first, run `select max(m_rep_date2) from HA_PRD_DM.UDF_CURR_REP` and write it down. Then add `b.m_rep_date2` to your query, and then run `select min(m_rep_date2) from ( .... )`  - in the parentheses, include your query (with `m_rep_date2` added to the `select` clause). If the result is the same date, which is what I expect, then 1.5mm rows is the correct answer. Are you missing additional conditions in the `ON` clause, perhaps?

Comment: @mathguy sorry I'm following, "Then add b.m_rep_date2" to what query where?

Comment: Take the "actual query" you posted. On the first line, right after the first word, `select`, add `b.m_rep_date2, ` (don't forget the comma). So it should read `select b.m_rep_date2, m_tp_str, .....` (and the rest of your query). This is just so that we have the date which is giving us trouble in the result of the query. Then, put the entire query in parentheses (so it becomes a subquery), and right before it write `select min(m_rep_date2) from` - this will select the earliest `m_rep_date2` returned by your query. I suspect it will be equal to the `max`, so 1.5mm rows is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136288/discussion-between-obabs-and-mathguy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using analytic functions:

```
SELECT id, b, c, d
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     (SELECT b.*, MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY b.id) as max_date
      FROM table2 b 
      WHERE built = 'yes'
     ) b
     ON b.id = a.id AND b.max_date = b.date;
```

Comment: This assumes the OP wanted max by id, even though that is not what his attempted query suggests. Another member **asked** (instead of simply posting a solution) and the OP answered that, indeed, he meant **global** max, not analytic max. This "shoot, then aim" approach to "helping" people isn't all that helpful.